# Relation between roles and pg_terminate_backend and/or pg_cancel_backend admin functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-9.6

Consider the following example:

A superuser `admin` executes the following commands in a PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE DATABASE admindb;
CREATE ROLE dbo WITH CREATEDB CREATEROLE;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE admindb TO dbo WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE ROLE user1 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'user1pw';
GRANT dbo TO user1;
ALTER ROLE user1 SET ROLE dbo;
```

In the next step, `user1` does the following:

```
psql -h 10.11.4.32 -d admindb -U user1
# creates a table in admindb database
CREATE TABLE test1 ( a INT, b INT);
# check pg_stat_activity

 datid | datname |  pid  | usesysid | usename | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port | backend_start | xact_start | query_start | state_change | wait_event_type | wait_event | state | backend_xid | backend_xmin | query
 17816 | admindb | 21314 |    17819 | user12  | psql             |             |                 |             |               |            |             |              |                 |            |       |             |          625 |<insufficient privilege>
(1 row)
```

Please see that query field shows insufficient privilege.

If I don't run `ALTER ROLE user1 SET ROLE dbo` while creating `user1`, the query field displays it correctly as given below.

```
 17816 | admindb | 18386 |    17819 | user12  | psql             | 192.168.0.12 |                 |       58794 | 2018-08-10 06:13:48.762903+00 | 2018-08-10 06:14:57.119916+00 | 2018-08-10 06:14:57.119916+00 | 2018-08-10 06:14:57.119917+00 |                 |            | active |             |          624 | select * from pg_stat_activity;
(1 row)
```

I would like to understand what causes this behavior.

As a consequence of this, if `user1` runs a long query and tries to cancel it by connecting using `psql` to `admindb` as user1 and running `select pg_cancel_backend(pid)`, it fails with the error.

```
ERROR:  must be a member of the role whose query is being canceled or member of pg_signal_backend
```

If I remove `ALTER ROLE user1 SET ROLE dbo`, then `user1` is able to cancel the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the `SET ROLE` changes your active user context to `dbo` right after you connect, but your “session user” still is `user1`:

```
SELECT current_user, session_user;

 current_user | session_user 
--------------+--------------
 dbo          | user1
(1 row)
```

In `pg_stat_activity` you can only see the sessions whose session user equals your currently active user, and `pg_cancel_backend` and `pg_terminate_backend` allow you only to affect backends whose session user equals your current user.

You can execute `RESET ROLE` to revert to `user1` and perform these operations.

Comment: if RESET ROLE isn't an option - what else can be done ?

Comment: What is your real problem? Why did you come up with this exotic setup? Maybe there is a simpler and better solution.